# Accessing the current remote session using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop

I have a Raspberry Pi which I use to run a Python script 24/7. I can remotely access it from my Linux laptop using SSH. But connecting to it using `ssh <username>:<address>` will create a new session instead of accessing the current session running in my Pi. Is there a way of using SSH so that I can see what my Python script is doing remotely and terminate and restart it remotely if necessary?

Effectively, I would like my laptop to be able to show me whatever is currently being displayed in my Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing so is using *tmux* (or *screen*, which is an older utility).

When you *ssh* into your Raspberry Pi install & run *tmux* (no options needed) you'll get a *tmux* session, that you can run your Python script it, to detach press *CTRL + B* following with the letter *D*.

The script will continue running in the background, to get back just write *tmux attach*.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for and it works as a charm. I've been using tmux for quite some time, but mainly for having multiple panes in my laptop's terminal. I wasn't aware you could attach and detach a session, much less doing so remotely via ssh. Thank you so much.